# XMLWorker: cell's vertical-align not working

Tags: css, itext, xmlworker

If you check this code:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td border="1">
            <table>
                <tr><td>Blah</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Blah</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Blah</td></tr>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td border="1">
            <table>
                <tr><td>Blah</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Blah</td></tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

In here:
   http://demo.itextsupport.com/xmlworker/

You will see this:
[image: vertical aligned to top]

But if you click on "transform" so that XMLWorker creates the PDF, this is the result:

[image: Not in top when converted to PDF]

So... is vertical align broken? how can I move that second table to the top of the parent's cell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to define the vertical alignment of the right cell.

I have adapted your HTML ([table4_css.html](http://itextpdf.com/sites/default/files/table4_css.html)):

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table border="1">
                <tr><td>Blah</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Blah</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Blah</td></tr>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td valign="top">
            <table border="1">
                <tr><td>Blah</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Blah</td></tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

You can find the source code to convert this HTML to PDF [here](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/xmlworker/ParseHtmlTable7). Take a look at the resulting PDF: [html_table_7.pdf](http://itextpdf.com/sites/default/files/html_table_7.pdf)

[image]

As you can see, introducing the `valign` attribute moved the right part up.

Comment: I though using `style="vertical-align: top"` was the correct way to go, but thanks!

Comment: though if I want to make several td's to vertical align top, and this is the way to go, I can't reuse a css class

Comment: do you know if there are plans on accepting the style `vertical-align: top`? because, as I said, if I want to make all of my `<td>`'s to vertical align top, I have to put a `valign="top"` in every single td... that is anti DRY

Comment: I think it's fairly easy to implement. Have you submitted a support ticket? Our technical roadmap is for a large part defined by what our paying customers need. If you are not a paying customer, please keep on using `valign`.

Comment: hmm i think its weird that nobody has asked for this.. I'm not a paying customer.

Comment: So you are open sourcing your complete code base as AGPL? That's nice! Where can people find your code?

Comment: Yes, the code is in my computer, in Argentina. You can come visit me, bring a diskette with you, and I give you the code

Comment: Make sure that you open source it before you use it in production. South-America is on our planning for 2016.